# Why does http://www.lop.com take me to my wamp server?

Tags: redirect, localhost, wampserver

I have wamp installed in my computer and when I type http://www.lop.com into the google chrome search bar, I'm redirected to localhost/, my wamp server. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 2):

lets have a look at your hosts file...

Comment: +1. That is indeed the most likely the reason. On another hand -- it can be DNS issue (record pointing to 127.0.0.1 due to some sort of misconfiguration) -- happens sometimes.